# Упростить написание кода макросом

Tags: c++, препроцессор

Имеется множество примерно таких методов:

```
void libvlc::Interop::LibVLCHelper::libvlc_media_player_set_media(libvlc_media_player_t * p_mp, libvlc_media_t * p_md)
{
    if (!m_vlc_media_player_set_media)
    {
        m_vlc_media_player_set_media = m_libvlc_->Resolve<vlc_media_player_set_media>(__func__);
    }
    (*m_vlc_media_player_set_media)(p_mp, p_md);
}
```

Хочу сделать примерно такой макрос:

```
#define MF(t, x, name) if (!(x)) { (x) = m_libvlc_->Resolve<t>(name); }
```

И определение на валидность упрощается соответственно до такого вида:

```
libvlc_media_player_t * libvlc::Interop::LibVLCHelper::libvlc_media_player_new(libvlc_instance_t * p_instance)
{
    MF(vlc_media_player_new, m_vlc_media_player_new, __func__);
    return (*m_vlc_media_player_new)(p_instance);
}
```

Да, он работает, но можно ли улучшить макрос до примерно такого вызова?

```
libvlc_media_player_t * libvlc::Interop::LibVLCHelper::libvlc_media_player_new(libvlc_instance_t * p_instance)
{
    MF(vlc_media_player_new, __func__);
    return (*m_vlc_media_player_new)(p_instance);
}
```

Для понятия: Макрос принимает тип, 1м параметром, подставляет `m_(тут тип)`, и вид примерно такой:

```
#define MF(t, name) if (!(m_#t)) { (m_#t) = m_libvlc_->Resolve<t>(name); }
```

> Не очень хорошо дружу с макросами, и не могу понять как такое
>   реализовать.
>
> Примечание: Имя поля всегда отличается от типа только добавочным `m_`

Comment: Ну да, можно, а что не так? Код с # не работает?

Comment: Можно в макрос и return засунуть по идее.

Comment: @VladD: Поправил вопрос. Нет, не все методы возвращают результат и имя передаваемых переменных почти всегда отличается.

Comment: @VladD: Да код с ＃не работает, `m_ is undefined`

Comment: А если вместо # написать ##?

Comment: Для конкатенации токенов следует использовать `##`, `#` служит для создания строкового литерала.

Comment: @VladD: Тогда да, преобразует нормально, но не может найти определение ：）

Comment: @VladD @VVT: `#define MF(t, name) if (!m_lib##t) { (m_lib##t) = m_libvlc_->Resolve<t>(name); }` Так сработало! Спасибо. Сам ошибся в именовании.

Comment: Отлично, тогда оформлю как ответ.

Comment: `__func__` тоже стоит засунуть в макрос: он раскрывается только после подстановки основного макроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код

```
#define MF(t, name) if (!(m_#t)) { (m_#t) = m_libvlc_->Resolve<t>(name); }
```

почти правильный. Для token pasting («склеивания» токенов) нужно использовать удвоенный символ диеза.

```
#define MF(t, name) if (!(m_##t)) { (m_##t) = m_libvlc_->Resolve<t>(name); }
```

(Практически одновременно тот же совет в комментарии дал @VTT.)

Answer (score 3):

**Долой макросы! Даёшь шаблоны и вывод типов!**

Предположу, что можно упростить код до следующего.

```
class /* имя класса, отвечающего переменной m_libvlc_ */ {
    ...

    template <class T>
    T& SafeGet(T*& member, const char* func) {
        if (!member) {
            member = Resolve<T>(func);
        }
        return *member;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
void libvlc::Interop::LibVLCHelper::libvlc_media_player_set_media(libvlc_media_player_t * p_mp, libvlc_media_t * p_md)
{
    m_libvlc_->SafeGet(m_vlc_media_player_set_media, __func__)(p_mp, p_md);
}
```

Ну и если всё-таки хочется макрос..

```
#define SAFE_GET(member) m_libvlc_->SafeGet(member, __func__)
```

и

```
void libvlc::Interop::LibVLCHelper::libvlc_media_player_set_media(libvlc_media_player_t * p_mp, libvlc_media_t * p_md)
{
    SAFE_GET(m_vlc_media_player_set_media)(p_mp, p_md);
}
```

P.S. Можно добавить в этот вызов и аргументы через `class ...Args` в шаблоне, но такой вариант показался приятнее.

Comment: Если вам интересно почему именно макрос, то посмотрите вот тут: [Github](https://github.com/isyami/libvlc.net/blob/master/src/libvlc.net/LibVLCHepler.cpp). Думаю поймете ：）10% функций только было реализовано. Возможно и 3%.

Comment: Ааа, так вы предлагаете передать указатель на указатель и записать в него адрес функции?

Comment: Почти. Я предлагаю передать указатель по ссылке и перед вызовом проверять его. А для отсутствия лишней `*` при вызове, разыменовывать сразу в функции, возвращая ссылку на метод