# Повторяющиеся типы и ошибка при компиляции шаблона

Tags: c++

Имеются определенные типы имеющие разные имена, но при этом они ничем более не отличаются. Вот так например:

```
typedef libvlc_media_t *(*vlc_media_new_path)(libvlc_instance_t *, const char*);
typedef libvlc_media_t *(*vlc_media_new_location)(libvlc_instance_t *, const char*);

typedef void(*vlc_media_retain)(libvlc_media_t *);
typedef void(*vlc_media_release)(libvlc_media_t *);

typedef libvlc_media_player_t *(*vlc_media_player_new)(libvlc_instance_t *);
typedef libvlc_media_player_t *(*vlc_media_player_new_from_media)(libvlc_media_t *);
```

Шаблоны в которых валится ошибка:

```
template<class T>
T resolve(const char* proc_name)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(GetProcAddress(m_library_, proc_name));
}

template<class T>
volatile T& get_safe(T*& member, const char* func)
{
    if (!member)
    {
        *member = resolve<T>(func);
    }
    return *member;
}
```

Вызовы:

```
libvlc_media_player_t * vlc::libvlc_media_player_new(libvlc_instance_t * p_instance)
{
    return m_yami_lib_->get_safe(m_vlc_media_player_new, __func__)(p_instance);
}

void vlc::libvlc_media_player_release(libvlc_media_player_t * p_mp)
{
    return m_yami_lib_->get_safe(m_vlc_media_player_release, __func__)(p_mp);
}

void vlc::libvlc_media_player_set_media(libvlc_media_player_t * p_mp, libvlc_media_t * p_md)
{
    return m_yami_lib_->get_safe(m_vlc_media_player_set_media, __func__)(p_mp, p_md);
}
...
```

Ошибка:

> error C2672: "yami_library::resolve": не найдена соответствующая
>   перегруженная функция error C2770: недопустимые явные аргументы шаблон
>   для "T yami_library::resolve(const char *)"

В таком случае, при передачи типа в шаблон, компилятор пытается произвести оптимизацию, и на этапе подстановки типов, они не подходят друг другу.

Как можно такое решить, за исключением приведения к одному имени типов?

Вопрос частично связан с данным ответом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804574/206435

Comment: @VTT: добавил пример вызовов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут лишние `*`. Если `m_vlc_media_player_new` имеет тип указателя на функцию, то `T` будет выведено правильно (как указатель на функцию) без `*`:

```
template<class T>
volatile T& get_safe(T & member, const char* func)
{
  if (!member)
  {
      member = resolve<T>(func);
  }
  return member;
}
```

`volatile` тоже ни к чему, да и функцию resolve можно вставить прямо сюда.

Comment: Но в таком случае произойдет запись в переданный указатель?

Comment: @Yami Произойдет, указатель же передается по ссылке.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!